# How to handle bidirectional one to one relationship in hibernate with Jackson

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I'm using `@JsonIgnore` Annotation to prevent infinite loops when creating the Json for the responses and it works fine for what I need, but I'd like to know if there is some alternative where the property is not actually ignored but also prevents the infinite loop.

For example, I have **entityA** with following properties:

```
int id
String name
EntityB example;
```

and **entityB** has

```
int id
String something
EntityA entityAExample //(this one goes with the JsonIgnore)
```

So if I get all the registers in entityA, response will look like this:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "name": "name",
    "entityB": {
                 "id":"1",
                 "something": "text"
               }
}]
```

And entityB will look like:

```
[{
   "id":"1",
   "something": "text"
}]
```

It works good for what I need so far, but I'd like that entity B could also include the entityA (or the list if is a many to one relationship) so the response look like:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "something": "text",
    "entityAExample": {
                      "id":"1",
                      "name": "name"
                      }
}]
```

So, doesn't matter which entity I query, it will always show the related records.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common bidirectional relationships problem when dealing with json.

I think the easiest way of solving this with Jackson is using `@JsonIdentityInfo`. You just need to annotate your classes with something like this:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class EntityA{
    ...
}

@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class EntityB{
    ...
}
```

What this does is that when an entity that has already been serialized before, that's the parent entity (EntityA), has to be serialized a second time starting the infinite recursion loop, it will not be serialized as usual.

Instead it will be serialized using the property that you specified in the annotation, that is the `id`.

In short, the annotation lets you specify an alternative representation of the object that will only be used when the entity starts an infinite loop, thus breaking that loop.

Following your example that would result in:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "name": "name",
    "entityB": {
                 "id":"2",
                 "something": "text"
                 "entityAExample": "1"                                       
               }
}]
```

You could also annotate only EntityB instead of both entities and that would result in:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "name": "name",
    "entityB": {
                 "id":"2",
                 "something": "text"
                 "entityAExample": {
                                    "id": "1",
                                    "name": "name",
                                    "entityBExample": "2"                                         
                                   }
               }
}]
```

You can use other properties too altough the 'id 'usually works fine. [Here's](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) the the official documentation and the [wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity).

[Here's](http://www.insaneprogramming.be/blog/2013/07/13/circular-dependencies-with-jackson/) an article explaining this in more detail and [another](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) one showing other ways of solving it.

Comment: I tried to use the solution explained, but I get a java heap space error when generating the json: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: This does not prevent the recursion.  And most of the ideas in the Baeldung article you link to above don't work either.  The only thing that seems to work is `@JsonIgnore`.