# Hibernate and JAX-RS Response with HQL Select

Tags: java, json, hibernate, inheritance, jax-rs

So I have the following.

I have a Entity called GroupEntity which has a groupId, name, and a userId which is the id corresponding to UserEntity.

What I want: A JSON Response with the groupentity and the userentity.name. But for some reason I'm getting a 505 error with no stacktrace whatsoever.

Service:

```
public GenericEntity<List<GroupEntity>> getMyGroups() throws HibernateException {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM GroupEntity g inner join g.teacher as teacher");
        List<GroupEntity> groups = (List<GroupEntity>) query.list();
        GenericEntity<List<GroupEntity>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<GroupEntity>>(groups) {};

        return entity;

    }
```

JAX-RS Resource

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMyGroups(){

    return Response.ok(groupService.getMyGroups(),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();

}
```

GroupEntity

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Group", schema = "pad_ijburg", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name")
})

public class GroupEntity implements Serializable {
    private int idGroup;
    private String name;

    @XmlTransient
    private UserEntity teacher;

    public GroupEntity(String name, UserEntity teacher) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public GroupEntity(){

    }

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser")
    public UserEntity getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public void setTeacher(UserEntity teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getIdGroup() {
        return idGroup;
    }

    public void setIdGroup(int idGroup) {
        this.idGroup = idGroup;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

UserEntity

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "User", schema = "pad_ijburg", catalog = "", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserEntity implements Serializable{
    private int idUser;

    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //ToDo Make this password secure!
    private String password;
    private boolean admin;
    private boolean teacher;

    //Lists below

    private Set<GroupEntity> teacherGroups = new HashSet<GroupEntity>(
            0);



        public UserEntity(String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password, boolean admin, boolean teacher) {
            this.email = email;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.password = password;
            this.admin = admin;
            this.teacher = teacher;
        }

        public UserEntity() {

        }

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "idUser")
        public int getIdUser() {
            return idUser;
        }

        public void setIdUser(int idUser) {
            this.idUser = idUser;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "email")
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "firstName")
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "lastName")
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "password")
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "admin")
        public boolean getAdmin() {
            return admin;
        }

        public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
            this.admin = admin;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "teacher")
        public boolean getTeacher() {
            return teacher;
        }

        public void setTeacher(boolean teacher) {
            this.teacher = teacher;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "idGroup")
        public Set<GroupEntity> getTeacherGroups() {
            return teacherGroups;
        }

        public void setTeacherGroups(Set<GroupEntity> teacherGroups) {
            this.teacherGroups = teacherGroups;
        }
    }
```

I think that it has something to do with the body writer. Problem is: I don't really know how to solve this.

Bodywriter error:

> 29-May-2016 02:29:43.679 SEVERE [http-nio-8079-exec-9]
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo
>   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,
>   type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList

Update:

I have fixed the bodywriter. But I still get an 505 error (no stacktrace). I have updated the service code above.

Update 2.0 POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.hva.folivora</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>IJBurg ReflectionAPP API</name>

<build>
    <finalName>api</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Ensures JSON Support for the RESTAPI    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Update 3.0

```
session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT g.idGroup, g.name, teacher.idUser FROM GroupEntity g inner join g.teacher as teacher");
    List<Object[]> groups = (List<Object[]>) query.list();

    //GenericEntity<List<GroupEntity>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<GroupEntity>>(groups) {};

    //return entity;

    return groups;
```

The following will return the following json response. The data is correct. But it is not returning in the correct format.

```
    [
  [
    3,
    "TestGroup3",
    3
  ]
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's very difficult to analyse your problem without a stack strace, but as a first step I would try to wrap your List in another Entity. See what happens because according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#ok-java.lang.Object-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-) you have that `It is the callers responsibility to wrap the actual entity with GenericEntity if preservation of its generic type is required`

Comment: @JoaoEsperancinha Problem is that there is no stacktrace error. This is an known issue. And I think it has to do with jersey-media-moxy trying to convert the list, but not being able to do so successfully. Problem is: I don't know why it doesn't work...

Comment: @JoaoEsperancinha I just got an error (luckily) 29-May-2016 02:29:43.679 SEVERE [http-nio-8079-exec-9] org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a quick alternative solution for you:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
    <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency creates an automated databinding for these kind of objects that you want to pass through in a JSON format. In your case you want a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to go through. You can find more info about [Genson here](https://owlike.github.io/genson/)

Comment: I'm still getting a 500 error. Just so you know: I don't have a messagebodywriter error anymore (see my initial post where I give an explanation on how I fixed it). Any tips on how to use genson. I might not be using it correctly. Can I use it alongside mediamoxy?

Comment: @TVH7 I don't see why there would be a problem with media moxy. For Genson there is really nothing you need to do. It just implements the bindings and the mappings. Can you show your complete pom.xml file?. I think that you ran into another different issue because 505 is a problem related with version missmatch with HTTP protocols between the server and the client. Find more [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E505.html). Also which sort of client are you using? If you made the client yourself please make sure that the library versions match or are updated to the most recent one.

Comment: It seems that it is an 500 error not an 505 error. One of my expception handlers was setup wrongly.

Comment: I have added the pom.xml

Comment: This might help, still trying though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532544/how-to-handle-bidirectional-one-to-one-relationship-in-hibernate-with-jackson

Comment: Can you try and put a breakpoint where you return the response and see if you can catch the running process there in debug mode? [500](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html) error clears up responsibility from the client and tells us that the problem is in the server, so  I'm wondering if the server is actually getting the response correctly or not.

Comment: Now trying to put the query in an object. I do get an json response now, just not the correct layout.